# echo out a word when num rows>0 FAILS. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

If the num_row is > 0 the aMsg2 should be echoing but it doesnt even when num_row is > 0. Whats wrong? 
UPDATE: whole code didnt fit into the post? xD

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT u.* FROM users AS u JOIN (SELECT visitorid FROM visitors AS v WHERE v.userid = $userid ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT 6) AS v1 ON u.user_id = v1.visitorid");
    ?>
    <table style="width:100%">

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $user = $row['user'];

      $res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE favorite='$user' AND l_user='$currentuser'");
      $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

      if($num_rows > 0){
        $aMsg2 = "Works!";
      }else{
        $aMsg2 = "";
      }
     ?>
        <tr >
          <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
       </tr>
          <?php
        }
        echo $aMsg2; //doesnt work
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: `$res` != `$result` AND `$num_rows` != `$num_rows2`

Comment: @Sean I updated the post SO didnt let me show the whole code :S

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows2 > 0){
```

Into

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($num_rows > 0){
```

Comment: Ops thanks. Still doesnt work tho

Comment: @anon I have updated my answer again.